# Why isn't a binary not being found in my PATH?

Tags: terminal, bash, python, path

I've got a Python project which uses a virtual environment. In my project folder, there is a `bin/` folder which contains all the executables needed by the project. To use these, you run `source bin/activate` to insert the path to that `bin/` directory to your `PATH` variable.

Now, most of the time this works as I'd expect. I run the source command and when I run `which python`, it shows the one I'd expect from the virtual environment. Sometimes however, it doesn't list that one. It lists a different one on my `PATH`. Here's an example of what I see:

We can see we are in the project directory:

```
$ pwd
/Users/dalemy/Projects/my_project
```

We can also see that the `python` and `python3` binaries (actually symlinks) are in the `bin/` directory:

```
$ ls -al /Users/dalemy/Projects/my_project/bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 dalemy  staff    7 10 Feb 15:16 /Users/dalemy/Projects/my_project/bin/python -> python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 dalemy  staff   44 10 Feb 15:16 /Users/dalemy/Projects/my_project/bin/python3 -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/bin/python3
```

Here we can see that this is the first entry in the `PATH` variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/dalemy/Projects/my_project/bin:/Users/dalemy/.poetry/bin:/usr/local/opt/python3/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/dalemy/Config/scripts:/Users/dalemy/.poetry/bin:/Users/dalemy/.local/bin
```

But when we ask about where Python is located, it doesn't find it:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

$ which python3
/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3
```

Running `type -a` shows the same thing:

```
$ type -a python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

I've got no idea why this is happening. The `bin/activate` command runs `hash -r` and I've run it manually to be sure that it's clearing out anything cached. If I remove every single entry on my `PATH` except for the first one, I just get that it can't be found.

Once it starts doing this, the only solution I've found is to remove the virtual environment completely and recreate it.

What could possibly be going wrong here?

Comment: Does `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/bin/python3` exist? If you recently updated your Homebrew stuff it would be `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/bin/python3`.

Comment: They do. It finds the Homebrew stuff just fine. But I don't want it to find that. I want it to find the binaries at the start of the PATH.

Comment: What does running `type -a python` and `type -a python3` outputs?

Comment: Updated the main body to use `-a`.

Comment: The only way I found to reproduce what you are seeing is if the symlink points to a non-existing file. Can you please run `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/bin/python3` (and subsequently for all further symlinks) to verify that all files and links actually exist?

Comment: Can you make sure no sub-shell is getting created under your virtual environment? Within the sub-shell, your original PATH will be resurrected. You may want to consider setting the PATH in `~/.bashrc` so that it is available in any invoked sub-shell.

Comment: @nohillside You were totally correct. It was a different version that existed at that path, not an identical one. As you said, it seems that a Homebrew upgrade caused the version to change, and therefore the path, breaking the symlinks. If you want to write this as an answer, I'll happily accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to reproduce what you are seeing is if the symlink points to a non-existing file. So best to use `ls -l` to verify that all the symlink targets actually exist, and fix the links if necessary.

More generally speaking: Unless you really need a specific version of python3 it might be better to just run

```
cd /Users/dalemy/Projects/my_project/bin
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 python3
```

or just rely on `PATH`.